# styles are `undefined` during test react application with jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, less

I'am creating a react application by using **less** instead of **css**, I added the less loader in the file `config-overrides.js` in order to use it with the package **customize-cra**. The application looks like perfect, nevertheless when I execute `yarn test` which launches **jest runner** all less styles are undefined so I cannot test if a component has a concrete className because it's undefined too. Should I add anything in the **jest** configuration in `package.json` in order to make less availale during testing ?

Thanks!

Comment: I suspect you'd need something like https://jestjs.io/docs/en/webpack#mocking-css-modules, but without a [mre] it's hard to say.

Comment: There aren't enough details here, and I haven't used customize-cra. See [answer], or just delete this.